After the latest update my laptop is stuck in a boot loop
https://youtu.be/8RIRgHbyBqI?si=PKs3L8zjDeUFFUN9
I just updated Ubuntu 24.10 and it gets stuck at the Ubuntu logo in a boot loop. I am just starting to learn Linux, so I don’t know what to do to fix this problem so that Ubuntu can boot normally.
Basically it is just keep showing me mouse pointer and looping back to the "20 YEARS Ubuntu" logo.

If I try to press ctrl-alt-f3 it lets me reach terminal but I don’t know what should I be doing there I already tried. Sudo apt update and upgrade both didn’t do anything

The following steps worked for me:

Access one of the tty-s, e.g. tty5 by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F5
Reconfigure gdm3 sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
Reboot

Hope that helps!
